# Div Background-color is not working

Tags: menu, background-color, nav

I am hoping to have a navigation bar run across the entire screen, with a purple background and a to have a the menu sit in the middle of the bar. Right now I cant get the background color to work.

My Css:

```
div#main-navigation {
background-color: #AC56B8;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
}
```

My Html:

```
<div class="main-navigation">
<ul id="menu">
<li>HOUSE</li>
<li>BABY</li>
<li>MORE</li>
<li>ABOUT</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong css selector `#` is for ids, to select element by class you have to use `.`, so the first line of your CSS must be: `div.main-navigation {`

Comment: Consider using backticks (`) in your answer to format code.

Answer (score 0):

Write `.` instead of `#`
`#` is for id, `.` is for class.

Answer (score 0):

Look for this:

Replace div#main-navigation for div.main-navigation

```css
div.main-navigation {
background-color: #AC56B8;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
<ul id="menu">
<li>HOUSE</li>
<li>BABY</li>
<li>MORE</li>
<li>ABOUT</li>
</ul>
</div>
```